# syntax error when writing find function for List

Tags: c++, list, syntax

I'm running into a syntax error which I am sure is correct:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
expected `;' before '*' token
```

### ListP.h

```
#ifndef LISTP_H
#define LISTP_H
template <typename T>
class ListP
{
private:
    struct ListNode
    {
        T item;
        ListNode* next;
    };

    ListNode* find(int index) const;
    ......
}
```

### ListP.cpp

```
template <typename T>
ListP<T>::ListNode* ListP<T>::find(int index) const
{
 ......
}
```

The error occurs at the line.

```
ListP<T>::ListNode* ListP<T>::find(int index) const
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the template function definition in the header file?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have 3 issues:

Missing semicolon after class definition:

```
};
```

Missing `typename`:

```
typename ListP<T>::ListNode* ListP<T>::find(int index) const
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more info.

and you should implement templates in header file

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for a good explanation.

Comment: "*you should implement templates in header file*" Not always and not necessarily (though in case of a general-purpose list, it is the only way). As general advise, however, this is unacceptable

Comment: @Walter: Why is it unacceptable? There are other ways, but implementing them in the header file is the most common.

Answer (score 0):

**1** your code is incorrect, you must add `typename` to disambiguate `ListNode` as a type (rather than a static data member):

```
template <typename T>
typename ListP<T>::ListNode* ListP<T>::find(int index) const
{
 ......
}
```

**2** As you implement your template in a source file, make sure all implementations actually used in your code (all files including the header) are actually instantinated in List.cpp. You can ensure that using `static_assert`, such that code using other implementations fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Template functions are usually implemented in the header file, don't put the definition in the cpp

Comment: Wrong. I often implement templates in .cpp files. This is very useful, as it reduces compilation time (of other files) substantially. It is only possible, if the total number of sensible instantinations is small.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the definition has to be available at compile time when a template instance is needed anywhere and though the implementation has to be in the header. Maybe implementing it in the cpp is only possible when the function is only used in that module? But I have to admit that my template knwoledge is rather limited...

Comment: No, it is generally possible. The linker will try to find the instantination. If it cannot find it, only then an error will occur.